# Turning a python for loop into a single line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I turn this for loop into a single line of code?

```
numbers = []
for i in range(51):
    numbers.append(i)

print(numbers)
```

Expected output is a list of numbers that contain 1 to 50 ([1...50])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
numbers = [i for i in range(51)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A range can be converted directly to a list

```
numbers = list(range(1,51))
```

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is sometimes helpful:

```
>>> numbers = list(range(51)); print(numbers)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
print(list(range(1,51)))
```

Or:

```
print([i for i in range(1,51)])
```